# sencha touch - how to use data store in initcomponent function of panel

Tags: javascript, ajax, sencha-touch, iteration, store

How to read the json object (result of ajax call) inside initcomponent of panel. I have used the following code

```
initComponent : function() {
Ext.regModel('allVisit', {
    fields: [
        { name: 'visitDate', type: 'date'},
        { name: 'doctorInfo', type: 'string'},
        { name: 'patientId', type: 'string'},
        { name: 'visitType', type: 'string'},
        { name: 'referedBy', type: 'string'},
        { name: 'visitId', type: 'string'},
    ]
});
var allVisitStore =  new Ext.data.Store({ 
    model: 'allVisit',
    autoLoad : true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        id: 'allvisit_app_localstore',
        url: '/RadMobApp/api',
        extraParams:{          
            action:'test',
            queryName:'GET_ALL_test',
            retFormat:'XML',
            patId: '123',
            keyValuePair:'yes'
        },
        // the return will be XML, so lets set up a reader
        reader: new Ext.data.XmlReader({
            // records will have an "T4" tag
            record: 'data'
        })
    }
});

var jsonObj = [];
        allVisitStore.load();
        allVisitStore.data.each(function() {
        jsonObj.push({xtype:"panel", title: this.data['visitDate'] + " (" + this.data['visitType'] + ") " + this.data['doctorInfo']  , html : this.data['patientId'], style : 'padding-bottom:10px;'});
        });
        this.items = jsonObj;

        RadMobApp.views.clinicalPanel.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
}
```

Data store iteration code(given below) is executed before receiving the ajax request value. I have used setTimeOut function for  the following set of code

```
                var jsonObj = [];
        allVisitStore.load();
        allVisitStore.data.each(function() {
        jsonObj.push({xtype:"panel", title: this.data['visitDate'] + " (" + this.data['visitType'] + ") " + this.data['doctorInfo']  , html : this.data['patientId'], style : 'padding-bottom:10px;'});
        });
        this.items = jsonObj;

        RadMobApp.views.clinicalPanel.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
```

but no use, I am getting the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use the load function like this which will make sure that it executes after the store is loaded!

```
activityStore.load(function(records, operation, success) {
    console.log('num of activities loaded: ' + activityStore.data.length);
});
```